# Creating an external (2-steps) signature with bouncycastle and SunMSCAPI

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

I'm trying to remove some deprecated BC code from my application, but I'm having problem switching the old CMSSignedDataGenerator.addSigner to the new API.

Our old code, which worked on Linux (PKCS11 provider) and Windows (SunMSCAPI) was something like this:

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

CertStore certStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(certChain)));

Attribute attrHash = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet( new DEROctetString(hash) ) ); 
Attribute attrcontentType = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.contentType, new DERSet( CMSObjectIdentifiers.data ) );
ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector(); 
v.add(attrHash); 
v.add(attrcontentType);

gen.addSigner(aPrivateKey, userCertificate, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1, new AttributeTable(v), null); 
gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certStore); 

CMSSignedData s = gen.generate(CMSSignedDataGenerator.DATA, null, false, getProviderName() ); 

return s.getEncoded();
```

The provider name would be either "SunMSCAPI" or whatever we are dynamically using for PKCS#11 on Linux.

Both addSigner and generate methods got deprecated in BC, so now I'm doing the following:

```
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(certChain));

    Attribute attrHash = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(hash)));
    Attribute attrcontentType = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.contentType, new DERSet(CMSObjectIdentifiers.data));
    ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
    v.add(attrHash);
    v.add(attrcontentType);

    ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider(provider).build(aPrivateKey);
    gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
            new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(provider).build())
                    .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(new AttributeTable(v)))
                    .build(sha1Signer, userCertificate));

    gen.addCertificates(certStore);
    CMSSignedData s = gen.generate(new CMSAbsentContent(), false);
    return s.getEncoded();
```

The problem with this new code is that it works perfectly when using "BC" as a provider, but when I switch to "SunMSCAPI" I get th following exception:

```
no such algorithm: SHA-1 for provider SunMSCAPI
```

This convoluted way of signing is just because we need to sign a digest, we don't have the full content available for signing, so I have to pass the digest pre-computed to the signing method.

Can anyone please help me find out what could possible be wrong with the above code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably because the SunMSCAPI provider supports Signature engine but does not support MessageDigest engine ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI ). For instance the SUN provider supports MessageDigest engine ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SUNProvider )

Comment: You're right @Egl ! removed the provider from the definition and now the JVM has to choose the appropriate provider for each use, correctly choosing another provider for the MessageDigest part and the SunMSCAPI for the signature proper. BTW: I think there should be a away for me to just skip the Message Digest engine, since I'm already receiving the digest from the server, but can't figure out how.